# Can't ping my LXC container

Tags: linux, networking, lxc

I have set up a linux container on my server. The problem I have right now is that I cannot ping my linux container from my laptop, but I can ping the hypervisor.

I created the LXC by using:

```
lxc-create -n tomcat1 -t ubuntu
```

and then starting it. I didn't set any IP or anything, as it did by it self- with a another C-network that is not mine. Could this be the problem?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In a default setup, a random class C will be chosen for the container's DHCP range. This also sets up a NAT/MASQ firewall on the host. As with any minimal NAT firewall, it only serves connections initiated from the server/container on the inside, but not from the outside.

One of the most used ways to reach the container is to setup a PREROUTING/FORWARD firewall rule, that will forward specific port (ranges) to the container.

Eg. if you have a webserver running in your container that you want to reach:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d [hypervisor_IP]/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination [container_IP]
```

This will forward the traffic that is going to your hypervisor's IP on port 80 (HTTP) to your container. So in your browser you'd go to http://[hypervisor_IP]/ and you will see the webpage that is served by your container's webserver.